# Is it good to use filter_var with htmlentities in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm validating a POST request variables and I used to do like this:

```
$email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
```

But now I searched and learned about filter_var and I'm doing the validation like this:

```
$email = filter_var(htmlentities($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

Which way is better? and for all types of input [phone - string - etc ..] What I have to use?

Sorry I'm a beginner and I've looked into the manual but I could't understand a lot.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Make tests with your codes and see.

Comment: `htmlentities` would turn `&` to `&amp;` but `&` is a valid email character while `;` isn't so don't use `htmlentities` to validate an email.

Comment: @apokryfos , then what I should use in string validation (like username, or comments..etc)?

Comment: That depends on your specifications. If you want to show them verbosely as the user has inputed them then store them as they are sent and use `htmlentities` to convert entities before displaying them on the page. If you want to strip tags out then use `strip_tags()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use the following line for emails:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

This will correctly remove illegal chracters from an email character (such as `;` and keep legal ones such as `&` or `+`

Using `htmlentities` may turn a legal email address to an illegal one which `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` will then break.

If you are dealing with user input for labels or descriptions then you can **store said input normally** (using prepared statements to allow the DB to escape the input correctly) and use `htmlentities` **when displaying it on the page**. Alternatively you can use:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, "description", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

This the string sanitize filter strips tags.

You can check more filters at : http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php