# Email validation using PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, email

I have a form for which i am trying to validate the email address. If the email address is incorrect i want a value of "Please type a valid email address." to be returned into the "email" input box on the form. What am i doing wrong? No validation is taking place. I receive the form information at my email and once submitted the user is sent to the "Thank you" page, but no validation. I can put anything in the "email" input and the form will submit.

```
<form action="../php/contact.php" method="post">
  <p>First Name:</p>
   <input class="box_style" type="text" name="first_name" required maxlength="20" />

  <p>Last Name:</p>
   <input class="box_style" type="text" name="last_name" required maxlength="25" />

  <p>Email:</p>
   <input class="box_style" type="text" name="email" required maxlength="50" />

   <p>Contact Number (optional):</p>
   <input class="box_style" type="text" name="contact_number" maxlength="12" />

  <p>How did you find us?</p>
  <select class="box_style" name="how" required>
    <option value="choose">Select...</option>
    <option value="referal">Referal</option>
    <option value="website">Website</option>
    <option value="search">Search Engine</option>
    <option value="card">Business Card</option>
 </select> 

 <p>Enquiries:</p> 
  <textarea class="box_style" name="inquiries" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

  <input class="box_style" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>   
 </form>
```

and this is the php

```
<?php

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

// define variables and set to empty values
$fName = $lName = $email = $cNum = $how =  $enquiries = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
$fName = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
$lName = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
$cNum = test_input($_POST["contact_number"]);
$how = test_input($_POST["how"]);
$enquiries = test_input($_POST["enquiries"]);

$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    print  "<p>Please type a valid email address.</p>";

header("Location: www.mysite/thankyou.com");
}};

$email_from = 'my@email.com';
$email_subject = "New Inquiry";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from" ." ". "$fName" ." ".    "$lName" ."\n".
"$inquiries"."\n".
"Referal Type:" ." ". "$how" ."\n".
"Contact Number:" ." ". "$cNum" ."\n";

$to = "my@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);


?>
```

Thank You

Comment: Looks like the validation happens, but you do nothing to deal with it being right or wrong

Comment: `print  "<p>Please type a valid email address.</p>";
header("Location: www.mysite/thankyou.com");` You output a response and then immediately load another page. So the response is lost.

Comment: Yes @Martin is right.  The best way to do this for a simple form processing script is to move all the logic into one script that posts to itself. You divide the logic into parts where you check if the request is a post at the top and set any errors there.  Then it falls through to a section where everything is either ok (then you send the email) or it's not, and you output the form again, usually with values filled in, and errors added to the display.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. PHP is completely new to me and I've pieced together the above from articles and posts so i am at a bit of an impasse. I cant say i altogether know how to resolve my problem from your answers as informative as they are. I understand what you are saying but going about correcting it is a different deal!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of the OP's code that demonstrates how to display the error message by having the action attribute of the form be the same url as that which displays the form. The code also exemplifies some nice touches for the user:

```
<?php

  include("php4myform.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Validate</title>
</head>

<body>
<form  action="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);  ?>" method="POST">
  <label for="email">Email: </label> 
   <input  id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $e_mess; ?>">
   <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
   <input  type="reset" id="clear" value="clear">  
 </form>

<script src="myJS4forms.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

php4myform.php:

```
<?php

$e_mess = "";

if ( isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST != null) {  
    $tainted_email =  trim($_POST["email"]);
    $sanitized_email = filter_var($tainted_email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    if( !filter_var( $sanitized_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) {
        $e_mess = "Please type a valid email address.";
    }
    else
    {
        // Data is good to go.

    }
 }
```

myJS4forms.js:

```
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

var email = d.g("email");
var reset = d.g("clear");


function selFoc(obj){
    obj.focus();
    obj.select();
}



window.onload = function() {
  selFoc( email );
};  


reset.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        email.value=null;
        selFoc( email );
});
```

A few notes:

The drawback of testing with $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] is that the user might submit an empty form.  Therefore, the PHP code in this example tests to see if the form was submitted and if the POST contains any data.

It is ill-advised to use htmlspecialchars() with filter_var and the parameter FILTER_EMAIL_SANITIZE; see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615794/is-it-good-to-use-filter-var-with-htmlentities-in-php) and [here](https://3v4l.org/SJbJB#output), too. The code employs htmlspecialchars() instead to safeguard `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` -- basis: this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/form-validation-with-php/).

I removed stripslashes() since magic quotes are deprecated and gone as of PHP5.4; see the online [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).  (Using addslashes() to escape data is inadvisable -- better to use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).) Also, filter_var with FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL will remove any slashes (see [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)).

Comment: You can improve your answer by using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL to sanitize your email before validating :)

Comment: Thank you; I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm working through all the information to see if i can piece it together.

Answer (score -1):

If you redirect the user using a "header()" function, you need to stop the execution of the script. So the correct way would be something like this:

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    print  "<p>Please type a valid email address.</p>";
    header("Location: www.mysite/thankyou.com");
    exit();
}
```

If you don't terminate the script, it will continue executing the rest of the file.

Secondly, if you print something to the user and immediately redirect him elsewhere, he will never see the message. If you want to do a redirection and show the message there, you need to store the message first, probably in a session variable, and then show it on the "landing page".